# Attempted to load class "Class" from the global namespace. Error Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi I have a class name "Customer" in a variable like:

```
$myclass = "Customer";
```

Now I have created object for this class at run time inside a service file:

```
namespace MyBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use MyBundle\Component\Data\handle\Customer;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyServices
{

    private $em;   

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;        
}

public function getClassCustomer($className)
{

   $object = new $className();
    }
}
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
Attempted to load class "Customer" from the global namespace
```

Even `Customer` class is already defined and included in the same file:

Please suggest what could be the Issue.
thanks in advance

Comment: Youre explanation is a bit chaotic. Please post minimal but full code snippet that will let us reproduce the issue. `use/BundleName/ClassFolder:` is not including anything.

Comment: Hi dragoste: actualy

namespace Mybundle\Service;

 use Mybundle\Component\DataFolder\Classess\Customer; I am using on the top of file:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you're using variable as class name, then `use` statement doesn't apply.

When you do

```
use MyBundle\Component\Data\handle\Customer;
new Customer();
```

It's resolved as

```
new MyBundle\Component\Data\handle\Customer();
```

But with this:

```
use MyBundle\Component\Data\handle\Customer;
$className = "Customer";        
$object = new $className();
```

It's still just:

```
$object = new \Customer();
```

Take a look [Example #3 on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-294) as it's similar case:

```
use My\Full\Classname as Another, My\Full\NSname;

$obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
$a = 'Another';
$obj = new $a;      // instantiates object of class Another
```

Comment: My class name is dynamic: it will be any class like customer and some time user etc.. then in this case?

Comment: You need full qualified class name in your variable (with full namespace).